# Read data from a HttpWebRequest asynchronously while downloading

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

How is it possible to read the received data from a HttpWebRequest asynchronously while the request is downloading the resource?

I want to download a file and immediately start processing the received bytes. I've found a lot of examples how to call the HttpWebRequest asynchronously but the data gets read not until the download has completed:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;

void StartWebRequest()
{
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the line

```
webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
```

you still haven't read any of the response body. [EndGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse.aspx) returns an HttpWebResponse on which you must call [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx). The stream contains the actual response body and you can read this as fast or as slow as you want using standard stream methods.